# What part of speech is the word "very" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Questlove is a very good drummer.

This question came from the first question on this show: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKUhS81fBtI

Isn't it an adjective? How is it an adverb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an adverb because it modifies an adjective - adverbs modify anything that isn't a noun. In this case, the adjective is 'good'. Very can be used as an adjective, however, in such phrases as 'the very soul of man'; here it lends weight to the noun.

Comment: There are a few instances where adverbs can modify nouns and noun phrases.

Comment: @BillJ What would these be? Nothing comes to mind.

Comment: In _Virtually his only friend_, the adverb "virtually" is modifying the noun phrase _his only friend_, and in _He ate almost the whole pie_, the adverb "almost" is modifying the NP _the whole pie_. And in _A shortage of timber internationally led to a steep rise in prices_, the adverb "internationally" is modifying the noun "shortage". Interesting, eh?

Answer (score 3):

"Very" is acting as an adverb in your sentence because it is describing the adjective "good."

An adjective describes something.

You can't say, "Questlove is a very drummer," so you see it cannot act as an adjective in this sentence.

A good rule of thumb is to put a noun right after the word you are wondering is an adjective.  If it makes sense, it's most likely an adjective.

Hope this helps you.  =)